# Testing for shift key release does not work

Tags: c, keyboard, osdev

I am developing a keyboard driver for my operating system. When you press a key, the keyboard driver gets triggered and converts the scan codes correctly. The problem now is that the driver can't detect the shift key being released. When you press and release the shift key, it continues to print characters in uppercase. Here is the code for the keyboard driver:

```
void keyboard()
{
    static char scancode[58] = { 0, 0, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=',
        0, 0, 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', 0, 0, 'a', 's', 'd',
        'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', '\'', '`', 0, '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n',
        'm', ',', '.',
        '/', 0, 0, 0, ' '
    };
    static char shift_scancode[58] = { 0, 0, '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+',
        0, 0, 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '{', '}', 0, 0, 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F',
        'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ':', '"', '~', 0, '|', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', '<', '>',
        '?', 0, 0, 0, ' '
    };
    unsigned char status;       // detects status of buffer
    char keycode;               //scancode
    char release;
    status = inportb(0x64);     // get status of port
    if (status & 0x01) {        // check if bit 0 is set
        keycode = inportb(0x60);        // get key pressed
        if (keycode == 42 || keycode == 54) {
            *shift = 1;         // shift is pressed.*shift is global and volatile
        }
        if (keycode == 0xaa || keycode == 0xb6) {       // part not working
            println("Shift release detected");
            *shift = 0;
        }
        if (keycode <= 57 && scancode[keycode] != 0 && *shift == 0) {   // check if keycode is a normal key and shift is released
            *buffer = scancode[keycode];
            printc(scancode[keycode]);
            release = inportb(0x60);
        }
        if (keycode <= 57 && scancode[keycode] != 0 && *shift == 1) {
            *buffer = shift_scancode[keycode];
            printc(shift_scancode[keycode]);
            release = inportb(0x60);
        } else {
            *buffer = keycode;  //used to check scancode
        }
    }
    outportb(0x20, 0x20);       //eoi
}
```

I know that the problem is in the one that is not being called at all because I did a memory dump. It shows that the shift key is released and the buffer was = `0xaa` but the `*shift` pointer was still set to 1 instead of 0. How do I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code, but something that looks problematic is the fact that you define `keycode` to be a char (which is signed 8-bit value). Any scancode >= 0x80 will be negative. Maybe you intend for `keycode` to be an `unsigned char`? As well its hard to tell what you intended here but is `if (keycode <= 57 && scancode[keycode] != 0 && *shift == 1)` suppose to possibly be `else if (keycode <= 57 && scancode[keycode] != 0 && *shift == 1)` (It appears and **else** might be appropriate?)

Comment: There is a helpful post by OSDev.org about PS/2 keyboard programming and scan codes. It may help you somehow. Click [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard) to find it.